# Serial Port Data Received Event not working at second Port

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I'm trying to listen multi Serial port by automatically creating a Serial Port object and assigning an event to it. The mapping function checks whether the received data is correct with TestMachine and returns true/false. However, the problem occurs when I try to put the code into a for or if loop, the first serial port receives the correct data (Mapping function return true) then the second port not received data, This only happens when one of 2 ports received the right result(Mapping function return true).

code below without If(true).

```
            SerialPort _serialPortA = new SerialPort(portA.ToString());
            _serialPortA.BaudRate = machineA.BaudRate;
            _serialPortA.Parity = machineA.Parity;
            _serialPortA.StopBits = machineA.StopBits;
            _serialPortA.DataBits = machineA.DataBits;
            _serialPortA.Handshake = machineA.Handshake;
            _serialPortA.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler((sender2, e2) => DataReceivedHandler(sender2, e2, machineA));
            try
            {
                if (!_serialPortA.IsOpen)
                {
                    _serialPortA.Open();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            SerialPort _serialPortB = new SerialPort(portB.ToString());
            _serialPortB.BaudRate = machineB.BaudRate;
            _serialPortB.Parity = machineB.Parity;
            _serialPortB.StopBits = machineB.StopBits;
            _serialPortB.DataBits = machineB.DataBits;
            _serialPortB.Handshake = machineB.Handshake;
            _serialPortB.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler((sender3, e3) => DataReceivedHandler(sender3, e3, machineB));
            try
            {
                if (!_serialPortB.IsOpen)
                {
                    _serialPortB.Open();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Code below not working. The different is only put code into if(true){...} block.

```
       if (true) {
                SerialPort _serialPortA = new SerialPort(portA.ToString());
                _serialPortA.BaudRate = machineA.BaudRate;
                _serialPortA.Parity = machineA.Parity;
                _serialPortA.StopBits = machineA.StopBits;
                _serialPortA.DataBits = machineA.DataBits;
                _serialPortA.Handshake = machineA.Handshake;
                _serialPortA.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler((sender2, e2) => DataReceivedHandler(sender2, e2, machineA));
                try
                {
                    if (!_serialPortA.IsOpen)
                    {
                        _serialPortA.Open();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
        }

        if (true) {
                SerialPort _serialPortB = new SerialPort(portB.ToString());
                _serialPortB.BaudRate = machineB.BaudRate;
                _serialPortB.Parity = machineB.Parity;
                _serialPortB.StopBits = machineB.StopBits;
                _serialPortB.DataBits = machineB.DataBits;
                _serialPortB.Handshake = machineB.Handshake;
                _serialPort10.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler((sender3, e3) => DataReceivedHandler(sender3, e3, machineB));
                try
                {
                    if (!_serialPortB.IsOpen)
                    {
                        _serialPortB.Open();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
        }
```

this is DataReceivedHandler function

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e, AnalysisMachine m)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            string res = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadExisting();

            res = res.Replace("\r", "");
            try
            {

                if (m.Mapping(res, m.Name))
                {
                    m.PostData();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your second `if(true)`:

***_serialPortB***.Handshake = machineB.Handshake;

***_serialPort10***.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler((sender3, e3) => DataReceivedHandler(sender3, e3, machineB));

So you're not hooking the event to `_serialPortB` but to a different port instead.